# How to fix a stuck loop with two of the same elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I have an array `imgs` with 4 elements (images links). The first two elements  of the array are the same. I have also a `modal_img.src` variable with one link. And I have two buttons: `Previous` and `Next`. I want to replace the value of `modal_img.src` with next value from the array, if the currently compared value from the array is the same as the current value of `modal_img.src`. It's such switching to the next element.

Code:

```js
    $(next).click(function() {
      for (var a = 0; a < imgs.length; a++){
        if(imgs[a] == modal_img.src) {
          if (a == (imgs.length - 1)) a = -1;
          modal_img.src = imgs[++a];
        }
      }
    });

    $(previous).click(function() {
      for (var a = 0; a < imgs.length; a++){
        if(imgs[a] == modal_img.src) {
          if (a == 0) a = imgs.length;
          modal_img.src = imgs[--a];
        }
      }
    });
```

`Previous` button works well, but `Next` is stucking when I go to the moment of two first the same elements. I can't see any next elements, the loop stops on this "double" element and the `Next` button looks like it doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Alright, I'll ask the dumb question.  Why do you need the same element twice in the `imgs` array, if it is causing you problems?

Comment: @Taplar `Imgs` array has images links. User adds images and in `imgs` array I have only urls of those images. If user will add two the same images (I can happen:D) then I have a problem.

Comment: Issues due to user interactions, gotcha, :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `break;` to exit the for loop after the assignment to `src`. Otherwise it is an infinite loop because of `a = -1`

```
$(next).click(function() {
  for (var a = 0; a < imgs.length; a++){
    if(imgs[a] == modal_img.src) {
      if (a == (imgs.length - 1)) a = -1;
      modal_img.src = imgs[++a];
      break;
    }
  }
});

$(previous).click(function() {
  for (var a = 0; a < imgs.length; a++){
    if(imgs[a] == modal_img.src) {
      if (a == 0) a = imgs.length;
      modal_img.src = imgs[--a];
      break;
    }
  }
});
```

To work around the issue of the image being there twice, a second solution:

This is a solution using a carousel object.

```
$(next).click(function() {
    carousel.next();
});

$(previous).click(function() {
    carousel.previous();
});

function createCarousel(n) {
    var a = 0;
    return {
        next: function() {
            a = (a+1)%n;
            modal_img.src = imgs[a];
        },
        previous: function() {
            a = (a+n-1)%n;
            modal_img.src = imgs[a];
        }
    };
}

var carousel = createCarousel(imgs.length);
```

Comment: I tried with this solution earlier, but without results :(.

Comment: I added a second solution which does away with the comparision of modal_img.src. Do you need more functionality, like adding or removing images from the imgs list?

Comment: Solution with `carousel` is brilliant, thank you, have a good day!